# Rails notifications with noticed gem not getting marked as read on polymorphic comments

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, notifications

I am creating a facebook style app as the final rails project for The Odin Project.  I have polymorphic comments on posts and am using the noticed gem to generate notifications in the navbar.  The notifications are working properly, except for when I try to mark them as read.  The links generated are taking me to the correct post comment.  I don't get an error, and the rails console is showing:

```
UPDATE "notifications" SET "read_at = $1 WHERE (params @> '{"post":{"_aj_globalid":"gid://odin-facebook/Post/1"},"_aj_symbol_keys":["post"]} AND "notifications"."recipient_type" = $2 AND "notifications"."recipient_id" = $3 [["read_at", "2023-04-02 19:55:28.721381"], ["recipient_type", "member"], ["recipient_id", 1]]
```

So, it looks like it's trying to set the read_at field, but when I look in irb, read_at is nil, and on the app, the notification counter doesn't change.

I followed a tutorial to get this far with it, but I think the problem comes from the fact I'm using polymorphic comments, which the tutorial did not.  I plan to eventually update the comment system so that you can comment on comments.  Notifications will  eventually encompass likes and friend requests in addition to the comment notifications.  I would greatly appreciate any help possible to point me in the right direction.  I will list all the relevant code below.  Note: I'm using member in place of user for devise because I plan to share a database on Heroku with another app that's already using the keyword user.  So, whenever you see member, that just means user.

Edit:  I have removed most of the code.  The problem seems to stem from this mark_notifications_as_read method in the posts controller.  As it is currently written, it is not marking the notification as read.  It is not giving an error, but it's not working.

here is the method in Posts_controller.rb:

```
def mark_notifications_as_read
   if current_member
     notifications_to_mark_as_read = @post.notifications_as_post.where(recipient: current_member)
     notifications_to_mark_as_read.update_all(read_at: Time.zone.now)
   end
 end
end
```

If I change it to something like this:

```
  def mark_notifications_as_read
    if current_member
      notifications_to_mark_as_read = @commentable.notifications.where(recipient: current_member)
      notifications_to_mark_as_read.update_all(read_at: Time.zone.now)
    end
  end
```

then I get a

```
undefined method `notifications' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy
```

The problem seems to be that I don't know how to properly structure the query to get within the collection proxy.

If I look at a notification in irb, this is what I get.

```
#<Notification:0x00007f237ac8e6d8
  id: 2,
  recipient_type: "Member",
  recipient_id: 1,
  type: "CommentNotification",
  params:
   {:post=>nil,
    :comment=>
     #<Comment:0x00007f237ac6e888
      id: 2,
      member_id: 2,
      commentable_type: "Post",
      commentable_id: 1,
      body: nil,
      created_at: Mon, 03 Apr 2023 20:07:47.836134000 UTC +00:00,
      updated_at: Mon, 03 Apr 2023 20:07:47.840325000 UTC +00:00>},
  read_at: nil,
  created_at: Mon, 03 Apr 2023 20:07:47.869464000 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Mon, 03 Apr 2023 20:07:47.869464000 UTC +00:00>]
```

And I'm not sure how to properly structure that code to work with my object.

Comment: I think that most people's eyes will glaze over when shown 400+ lines of code. My recommendation is that you take another try at this post and explain in step-by-step detail what you expect to have happen. Walk us through the specific code that runs, e.g., "I click button *x* which fires controller action *y* which fires model method *z* which produces logs *a* indicating that *b* occurred which I do/do not expect, instead I do/do not expect *c* to have occurred, and I run *d* to confirm that *b* did/did not occur instead of *c*." Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yeah, I guess I did go a little overboard on providing code.  I think my eyes are glazing over a bit too.  I'll edit the post.